# What's the equivalent scheme in DC Mode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

Im trying to calculate the resistances \$R_1, R_2, R_3, R_D, R_S \$ so i was tempted to study this circuit in DC mode [image]

is this the correct equivalent scheme in the DC mode : [image]

does the \$R_3\$ and \$R_S \$ resistor stay independent no wire connects them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the DC equivalent circuit looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNjuac.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how can i calculate \$ I_{DQ_2} \$ so i can find the resistance \$ R_d \$ please?

Comment: And the technical requirements are? And I hope that you see that for this circuit we have: I_DQ1 = I_DQ2